# Which REST API call would I use to target an individual device for MobilePush?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobilepush

Can anyone tell me which REST API call would I use to target an individual device for MobilePush?
I have a use case where we need to send a targeted push notification to an individual device and then deep link them into a particular page in the application.
I dont see anywhere obvious in the documentation.

If someone could help with the call and an example payload it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I added the marketing-cloud tag to your question but then it occurred to me that you could be referring to a Custom Notification that is delivered to the user's mobile device. Can you confirm if your question is marketing cloud specific?

Comment: My apologies, I meant to add Marketing Cloud. Yes this is relating to Marketing Cloud Mobile Push. We would like to deliver a notification to a specific users device with a deep link into the app.

Answer (score 2):

`/push/v1/messageContact/{message ID/send`

With this endpoint you can target a contact by `Contact Key` or `Push Token`.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a bell notifications via Apex for a specific user(s);  does this work for you? See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/286556/10073

It calls the `/services/data/{version}/actions/standard/customNotificationAction`

Comment: Unfortunately not but thanks for the suggestion. In this instance we have an external app which when a user meets certain criteria, the app will send a call to the MC mobilepush API to hopefully send a push notification to that specific user.

Answer (score 0):

if you have already created a message in Mobile Push and want to target via subcriberKey

```
/push/v1/messageContact/{messageID}/send
```

body:

```
{
    "subscriberKeys": [
        your_subscriber_key
    ]
}
```