# How to notify users

Tags: feeditem, custom-notification

I want to **notify** my users without any specific record related.

Insert a **FeedItem** with the **parentId** set to the userId does not create the red notification in the top-right corner **bell**.

Do I need to use **CustomNotification** or can it be achieved with FeedItem?

Please, note that I am not asking for a way to create bell notifications in apex, I know there is a one with "Custom Notifications". I am asking if a similar result can be achieved with FeedItem, which is unresponded [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/256999/84580), where  Enrik Hysko raises the same concern that I have,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bell notifications via apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256989/bell-notifications-via-apex)

Comment: related https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.collab_email_settings.htm&type=5

Comment: @NagendraSingh I found that post, but like in the accepted response, there is a comment  that says "I tried this but it created only Chatter post, no bell notification. – Enrik Hysko" . I am facing the same, but that comment has no reply

Comment: @cropredy I do not want email notifications, but bell notifications inside of salesforce org

Comment: @NagendraSingh Please, note that I am not asking for a way to create bell notifications in apex, I know there is a one, "Custom Notifications". I am asking if a similar result can be achieved with FeedItem, which is unresponded in the supposed "original post", so the Post Itself is not repeated. Kindly remove your "close-duplicate vote".

Comment: Maybe try the same technique I suggested below with the feed item... will it allow you to set a target to a dummy id?

Comment: Sorry, I do not really understand your suggestion. Do you suggest to use a customNotification, specifying the targetId as the created feedItem.Id ? If so, That is redundant for me, because I would still need custom notification, so there would be no place for feedItem

Comment: I was meaning set the ParentId to a dummy value, but I'm thinking it's not going to let you do that.

Comment: I found the problem. Bell notification with FeedItem was not appearing because, in testing context, my same admin user that was creating the feedItem was the parentId too. When I changed the parentId to be a different user and logged in the org as him, the notification appeared.

Answer (score 2):

Responding my own question:

Bell notification with FeedItem is achievable and it should appear.

However, if the same admin user that is creating the feedItem is the parentId too, no notification will appear.

If you changed the parentId to be a different user and log in the org as him, the notification will appear.

Comment: Bell notification is achieved by CustomNotification class easily. As given here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/318068/45062

Comment: I know, but I wanted to achieve a similar result with FeedItem